# Float comparison in C

Tags: c, if-statement, compiler-errors, floating-point, precision

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float x = 0.6;
    if (x == 0.6)
        printf("IF");
    else if (x == 0.6f)
        printf("ELSE IF");
    else
        printf("ELSE");
}
```

This code gives output **ELSE IF**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float x = 0.5;
    if (x == 0.5)
        printf("IF");
    else if (x == 0.5f)
        printf("ELSE IF");
    else
        printf("ELSE");
}
```

This code gives output **IF**

Even though both the programs looks same but why there is difference in the outputs? Why this is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `0.5` has an exact representation in IEEE-754 binary formats (like binary32 and binary64).  `0.5` is a negative power of two. `0.6` on the other hand is not a power of two and it cannot be represented exactly in `float` or `double`.

Comment: Did you just happen to know that ?

Comment: @Noob I'm affraid I don't understand your question.

Comment: The answer was pretty amazing. That's it ! I was wondering how you knew it.

Comment: Sorry ouah I did not understood your point. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @AnujGarg numbers `0.5`, `0.25`, `0.125`, etc. are negative power of two and therefore can be represented without representation errors in `float` and `double`. To get more information on floating points I can suggest you to read http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @AnujGarg - Try representing 0.5 in binary. And then try the same for 0.6. You'll get the point.

Comment: @Noob well I think I consider this fact some of the basics of IEEE-754 but floating point is a broad and not easy subject.